# Ansible failed when connect to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

I just created a playbook to bring up an EC2 instance, my original image is `ami-63b25203` and everything runs normally, but when I changed this image to `ami-9abea4fb`. I got this error

```
fatal: [ec2-52-34-133-13.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com] => SSH Error: Permission denied (publickey).
        while connecting to 52.34.133.13:22
It is sometimes useful to re-run the command using -vvvv, which prints SSH debug output to help diagnose the issue.

TASK: [Jenkins | Add Jenkins repository] **************************************
FATAL: no hosts matched or all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

and, this is my playbook on github: https://github.com/hly189/Ansible/blob/master/ec2.yml

and, this is the configuration for my ansible.cfg

```
[defaults]
#ask_sudo_pass = True
host_key_checking = False
remote_user = ec2-user


[ssh_connection]
control_path = "%(directory)s/%%h-%%r"
ssh_args = -o ForwardAgent=yes
```

Can anyone show me of how to fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, try changing remote_user= by only user=, then do a chmod 600 hoa_ly.pem file, and try with ssh.

You miss the key pair configuration, I use this just adding a new ssh identity on my ~/.ssh/config as well:

IdentityFile ~/.ssh/hoa_ly.pem

Comment: Actually, it got fixed by changing `remote_user` to `user`. Btw, can you please explain me why, because when I used `remote_user` with Amazon Linux, which is different ami, it was still normal

Comment: What is your ansible version?

Comment: My ansible version is 1.9.3